# Create a variable number of vectors in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I can create a 2D array of size `n*m`by doing:
`vector< vector< int > > foo(n, vector< int > (m))`.

Suppose that at runtime I'm given a variable number of values,
e.g. `v_1, v_2, v_3, ..., v_k` and want to create the following:

`vector< vector< ... vector< int > ... > > foo(v_1, vector< ... > (v_2, vector< ... > ..));`

In other words create a multidimensional array of size `v_1* v_2 * v_3 ... *v_k`. How can I do this? Is this possible?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to do what you seek. Since the depth of the nesting must be known during compilation. But it seems to me like an XY question. Your problem is X, you think Y is the solution, so you ask about Y rather than about X.

Comment: @StoryTeller That's true, but I found out how to solve `X` in another way. Just wanted to see if it's possible to solve it using `Y` as well.

Comment: I misread the original question - and yes, I think there isn't any (trivial) way to do this. The solution by Tony D below was what I was going to suggest - but it gets quite awkward and complicated very quickly.

Comment: Oh, alright than. +1 than for the interesting question :)

Comment: Each vector<...> is a *type*. What you're asking for is near-trivial at compile-time using a variadic template (ex. `MyData<int,10,20,30>` results in a effectively a three-tier nexted vector of vector of vectors). It is a little more complicated for runtime with variadic arguments at construction. (ex. `MyData<int>(10,20,30)`). But to do it *all* at run-time with variable list of dimensions as an argument list would be non-trivial (but still doable with enough work). It will *not*, however, resemble a `vector<vector<vector...>>>` trivial format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this - data type must be set at compile time.  That said, it's quite practical to use a single array with the correct total number of elements, and create a mapping so that your logical `[i1][i2][...]` is found at say `[i1*v2*v3...vk + i2*v3..vk + ...]`.

Comment: +1 this is exactly how I have done it in the past. The support "indexer" that peels off each `[]` operator and returns another indexer until you reach the final dimension is the hardest part (if having `ar[i1][i2][i3]...[iN]` is important to you. If not, and a regular function interface is acceptable, this is *very* doable in a small amount of code). Nice answer, btw.

Answer (score 4):

You need [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/variant.html), which can handle this. You can create a recursive_wrapper that will allow you to nest the contents arbitrarily. There are other approaches, such as one single flat array of large size, or you can use inheritance and dynamic allocation, but they involve quite a bit more hassle.

```
typedef boost::variant<
    int,
    std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_>
> variant;

int main() {
    std::vector<variant> var; // Assume at least 1 dimension
}
```